# SAP Hana One : Unable connect with Hana Studio

Tags: hana

I have created a SAP Hana One Instance for SPS11. But i never get any username or password to connect with SAP HANA Studio? Can someone help to connect SAP Hana One instance with SAP Hana Studio.

Comment: You should have gotten/requested Database credentials and then in the SAP HANA Studio or Eclipse, in one of the HANA relevant perspectives, create the connection under Systems tab and use mentioned credentials to login.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have SAP Logon Pad installed on your local PC.
If you can see the SAP system in the local SAP Logon Pad, you can see the same SAP systems in SAP HANA Studio.

Please check how you can [configure the saplogon.ini for SAP HANA Studio](http://www.kodyaz.com/sap-abap/sap-systems-list-in-eclipse-from-sap-logon-pad.aspx) in Eclipse IDE here.
Probably the referenced saplogon.ini file is empty. You can copy and paste the file populated with SAP systems in your environment.

I had the problem so that I could not see any SAP systems and had to manually configure for all SAP systems to logon. The solution will help you too to logon with SSO

Comment: Shouldn't he have a Database user, and what does NW stack credentials have to do with HANA instance?

Answer (score 0):

When you install SAP HANA server, you need to create a SYSTEM superuser. You can connect from HANA Studio using that credential.

Answer (score 0):

To connect to a hana db you need to know the Hostname and Instancenumber of the hana db.
For hana 2 systems the port of the nameserver on system db is
313
On this server you can use the view M_SERVICES in the SYS_DATABASE schema to see the sql ports of the indexservers of your tenant dbs